# how to correct this err: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

```
@isTest(seeAllData=true)
public class BatchFirstCloseWonOppOwnerOnAccountTest { 

    static testmethod void ClosedWonOppOwner(){

         Database.QueryLocator QL;

        Database.BatchableContext BC;

         test.startTest();

       List<Opportunity> opp = new List<Opportunity>();

          for (Integer i=0;i<10;i++) {

            opp.add(new Opportunity( name='opportunity '+i, StageName='Prospecting', CloseDate=Date.today(), Accountid= ));
            //opp.add(new Opportunity( name='opportunity '+i, StageName='ClosedWon', CloseDate=Date.today() )); 
          }

        BatchFirstCloseWonOppOwnerOnAccount bfc=new BatchFirstCloseWonOppOwnerOnAccount();

         QL = bfc.start(bc);

        Database.QueryLocatorIterator QIT =  QL.iterator();
        while (QIT.hasNext())
        {
            Opportunity opp1 = (Opportunity)QIT.next();            

        }        

        Id BatchId = Database.executeBatch(bfc);
         bfc.execute(BC, opp);
         bfc.finish(BC); 
         test.stopTest();


    }
}
```

my test class is given above any suggestions?

Comment: You seem to be asking very similar questions over and over, and this error message is one of the clearest ones that Salesforce can give you. I'd suggest taking a few steps back, and spending some time trying to understand each and every individual token that you're using both in this test class, and the class that is being tested. Also, I'd recommend reading [ask]. If nothing else, please endeavor to include more details in your questions. Providing more details and being more specific should result in you receiving more high-quality answers.

Answer (score 2):

The issue resulting in this error is a mistake in the test class rather than a bug in the batch class, although this version of the test class, as written, will not compile or run.

As the error specifies, you cannot attempt to `update` an sObject instance which doesn't contain an Id value. Most commonly this would occur if you call `update` when you meant `insert`, or if you construct a new sObject in Apex with field values to update but forget to populate `Id`.

In this case, you're directly calling your batch class's `execute()` method with a list of Opportunities that have not been inserted into the database. Presumable, your batch class attempts to `update` these instances, which it cannot do, resulting in an exception.

Your test class has several other issues, however. First and foremost, you can and should remove `seeAllData=true`. Your class has the beginnings of code to insert your own Account and Opportunity instances to use in the tests, which you absolutely should do. Using `seeAllData=true` is very bad practice and makes your tests fragile.

You should also remove the code that directly calls `start()`, `execute()` and `finish()`. Instead, you should insert all relevant test data and enqueue your batch class, as you already do. Your enqueued batch class will run synchronously after you call `Test.stopTest()`, and you can query against your test data and make assertions about what your code has done at that time.

There are sometimes good reasons to call `start()`, `execute()` and `finish()` directly in a test class, but none of them appear to be in play here. It looks like you intended to iterate over the results of your query and add them to a List, but you don't do so. (Because the objects aren't inserted, the query would just return any Opportunities existing in your sandbox, because of `seeAllData = true`. This means that your direct call to `execute()` will fail, but the enqueued batch *might* succeed, making your results very confusing if you got past the exception).

It is **critical** to make assertions in your test class. If you don't do so, what you have is commonly called a "smoke test" that demonstrates nothing about your code's behavior except that it does not crash in a small set of circumstances.

The Salesforce Developer blog has an [ongoing series](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/month-of-testing-apex-testing-in-depth-part-2-of-3.html) about writing good unit tests. I would strongly encourage you to take advantage of that resource, as well as Trailhead's unit on [testing Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing).